# Shorten a long if statement

Tags: vba, if-statement

How can i write this code in a shorter way?

This is only part of my code. It is very long and my system runs it a bit slow. I want this to run every time user adds a value like number in range N2:P & last row.

```
Sub TEST()

lastrow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

'---1
If Cells(i, "P").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "P").Value <= 5 And Cells(i, "I").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value And Range("P" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value <= Cells(i, "I").Value Then
Cells(i, "P").Value = Range("P" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value

'----2
ElseIf ((Cells(i, "P").Value >= Cells(i, "I").Value) Or (Range("I" & i).Value - Range("P" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value)) And Cells(i, "O").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "O").Value <= 5 And Cells(i, "H").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value And Range("O" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value <= Cells(i, "H").Value Then
Cells(i, "O").Value = Range("O" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value
'---3
ElseIf ((Cells(i, "P").Value >= Cells(i, "I").Value) Or (Range("I" & i).Value - Range("P" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value)) And Cells(i, "N").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "N").Value <= 4 And Cells(i, "H").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value And Range("N" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value <= Cells(i, "H").Value Then
Cells(i, "O").Value = Range("N" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value
Range("N" & i) = vbNullString

'----4
ElseIf ((Cells(i, "P").Value < Cells(i, "I").Value) Or (Range("I" & i).Value - Range("P" & i).Value >= Range("K" & i).Value)) And Cells(i, "O").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "O").Value <= 5 And Cells(i, "I").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value And Range("O" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value <= Cells(i, "I").Value Then
Cells(i, "P").Value = Range("O" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value
Range("O" & i) = vbNullString
'---5
ElseIf ((Cells(i, "P").Value < Cells(i, "I").Value) Or (Range("I" & i).Value - Range("P" & i).Value >= Range("K" & i).Value)) And Cells(i, "N").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "N").Value <= 4 And Cells(i, "I").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value And Range("N" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value <= Cells(i, "I").Value Then
Cells(i, "P").Value = Range("N" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value
Range("N" & i) = vbNullString

'---6
ElseIf ((Range("I" & i).Value - Range("P" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value) Or (Range("H" & i).Value - Range("O" & i).Value < Range("K" & i).Value)) And Cells(i, "N").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "N").Value <= 4 And (Cells(i, "H").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value Or Cells(i, "I").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value) Then
Range("N" & i) = vbNullString
MsgBox "You already"


'---6
ElseIf Cells(i, "I").Value = vbNullString And Cells(i, "H").Value = vbNullString And Cells(i, "N").Value >= 1 And Cells(i, "N").Value <= 4 Then
Range("N" & i) = vbNullString
MsgBox "There is no "
```

Comment: Note: I removed the [shortcode] tag - I can't see what this question has to do with Wordpress.

Comment: If you inherited this code, just find another job.

Comment: It is too convoluted to really understand. One thing that might help is to at the top of the loop assign that various things like `Range("P" & i).Value ` to single letter variables like `P` and the various conditions can then be written much more compactly, sort of like `If P < Q and N < Q Then...`. That will shorten the code, make the logic more understandable, and reduce the overhead of constantly accessing cells.

Comment: I can't give any hints on shortening the code (because I can't understand what it is attempting to do), but you can probably speed it up (at least a bit) by storing all the values like `Cells(i, "P").Value` as variables so that you are not constantly accessing the worksheet.  (And, be consistent - either use `Range("P" & i)` or use `Cells(i, "P")` - don't mix and match them as it just makes the code even more unreadable.)

Comment: thank you for your response John.

Comment: thank you for your response YowE

Answer (score 4):

Extract functions for your tests that return a `Boolean`.  For example, the first `If` test (line continuations added for clarity)...

```
If Cells(i, "P").Value >= 1 And _ 
   Cells(i, "P").Value <= 5 And _
   Cells(i, "I").Value >= Cells(i, "K").Value And _
   Range("P" & i).Value * Range("K" & i).Value <= Cells(i, "I").Value Then
```

...can be written as the following function:

```
Private Function WhateverTheTestIsFor(rowNumber As Long) As Boolean
    Dim columnI As Variant
    Dim columnP As Variant

    columnP = Cells(rowNumber, "P").Value
    columnI = Cells(rowNumber, "I").Value
    columnK = Cells(rowNumber, "K").Value
    Select Case True
        Case columnP < 1
        Case columnP > 5
        Case columnI < columnK
        Case columnP * columnK > columnI
        Case Else
            WhateverTheTestIsFor = True
    End Select
End Function
```

Then your first `If` clause becomes:

```
If WhateverTheTestIsFor(i) Then
```

Note that as mentioned in the comments, you should only read the values from the Worksheet once.  There are other issues with the code too - you need to qualify your references to `Cells` and `Range`, and *pick a convention to use between the two*.  Mixing `Cells(i, "K")` and `Range("K" & i)` is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use data validation for this?
You can create multiple rules that overlap in complex ways without writing complex  code.

in excel, select your desired range PN:PN,
then in the data tab select data validation.
you will see a wizard that can help you add layers of rules that can warn users whenever specific  values ate entered, or even prevent entry of unacceptable values.

http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/data-validation.html

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer (and as such I would typically downvote it since comments don't belong in the answers). But -- it is a good comment which might help OP. Perhaps you could add a bit more detail to convert it into a full-fledged answer.

Comment: thanks john, the app I am using doesn't allow comments on the post (I see the website does) and since i am new-I didn't know the difference.   I'll do better next time.

Comment: When you get enough rep (which can happen pretty quickly) then you will be able to comment. Your edit has turned it into a decent (albeit short) answer, so +1